# Use Chebyshev's theorem to approximate a probability

Tags: probability, statistics

So I'm having this question in probability and statistics that states the following:

We have an array of **Independent** random variables **Xn**, n>0, with a **Poisson Distribution P(4)**, approximate the probability of $\sum_{i=1}^{36}Xi > 120$.

I think I'm supposed to use Chebyshev's theorem but I don't know how to apply it to solve the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Chebyshev's theorem lets you find  a bound for the probability. The use of the word 'approximate' here is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For a non-negative random variable $Y\geq 0$ we can use Markov's inequality to write
$$
P(Y>a)\leq \frac{EY}{a}.
$$
In your case $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{36}X_i\sim \text{Poi}(4\times 36)$ and $a=120$.